# ignore null parameter in a jpql query

Tags: jpql

I want to make a filter with a query in jpql.
My problem is: if I have 4, 5 ,6 , etc parameters I want to ignore one or more parameter when i make the query. Why? because I want to turn on or off some filters.

Example

I want to see all users with the state  "fired" so I want to make the query like this:

"select u from Users as u where u.state = :parameterState"

Where parameterState is my parameter that contains the string "fired".

So far so good, but I want to make the SAME query sending a null (with parameterState) to ignore the filter and show me all the users.

"select u from Users as u where u.state = :parameterState"
Now the parameterState have a null value and I need to ignore the "where u.state = :parameterState" to make this query:

"select u from Users as u"

I know that I can make switch-cases with all the posible ways to make the 2 querys, but I want to make a GENERIC WAY to invoque 1 unique query and solve all.

Note that if I want to make 2 filters (with 2 parameters) I need to make 4 different querys (in a Switch-case), if I need 4 filters (with 4 parameters ) there is 16 different ways to make the query.

Thats why I want to make a ONE generic call with ignore a NULL parameter, Is it posible?

Comment: That's why the criteria API exists. To be able to dynamically compose queries based on... criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I investigate about criteria API, but it seems useful to change the Class of one parameter and make the query dynamic. But I want to make "disappear" a parameter in my query. Can you be more specific? I don't know much about criteria API, an example will be much appreciated.

Comment: `if (param1 != null) { add predicate to criteria query for param1}; if (param2 != null) { add predicate to criteria query for param2};`

Comment: that's precisely the problem... why not just make a switch with all the parameters in every state (in null and not null)? if I make a predicate with param1, param2, param3, param4 the problem don't dissapear.

Comment: Have you tried : `select u from Users as u where (:parameterState is NULL or u.state = :parameterState)` ?